# PHP mail not working in script (php, nginx, ubuntu linux)

Tags: php, email

I have a php script and I cannot send mail with it.
If I send a message with ssh it works like a charm.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['bit_send'])) {
  $name    = protect($_POST['name']);
  $email   = protect($_POST['email']);
  $subject = protect($_POST['subject']);
  $message = protect($_POST['message']);

  if (empty($name) or empty($email) or empty($subject) or empty($message)) {
    echo error($lang['error_1']);
  } elseif (!isValidEmail($email)) {
    echo error($lang['error_2']);
  } else {
    $msubject  = '[' . $settings[name] . '] ' . $subject;
    $mreceiver = $settings['supportemail'];
    $headers   = 'From: ' . $supportemail . '' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . '' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $mail      = mail($mreceiver, $msubject, $message, $headers);
    if ($mail) {
        echo success($lang['success_1']);
    } else {
        echo error($lang['error_3']);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions? What do you mean with "send mails with ssh"?

Comment: Hi Simon, Its now working. send mails with ssh i mean i can send mail in terminal calling sendmail in commandline.

Answer (score 0):

changed sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail to /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i and now my mail is working.

The only thing i need to change is the sender which is now www-data.